# How can I remove a program from "Open With"?

Tags: finder, windows, vmware

I recently installed VMWare Fusion and added Windows 7.  Now when I right-click on a text file and choose Open With, there's an option to open with Notepad in Windows 7.  This is not something I want enabled.  How can I remove this choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is to install [RCDefaultApp](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14618/rcdefaultapp) and change the file association for text files.

Another solution is to disable Windows application integration for that virtual machine. To do that open the virtual machine, go to the *Virtual Machine* menu and select *Settings...*. Change the settings for *Default Applications*. You likely want to uncheck *Run Windows applications from you Mac's Applications folder*

[image]

Comment: Looks handy, thank you.  Unfortunately it appears that it's no longer maintained; at least one commenter notes it doesn't work with Mountain Lion.

Comment: Hmm, I use it with Mountain Lion.

Comment: Nice, @Hair.  Changing the settings via Fusion is the right answer.  I've been all through those settings, but didn't see that.  Note that a reboot is required for the changes to take place.  Thank you!